# Split a dataframe into multiple dataframes and perform procedures on the dataframes in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I have a data frame dfA. That contains over a million records. 
I want to split the dataframe into multiple dataframes based on the 'GROUP_ID' and then I want to perform some operations on the dataframes. This loop will create a dataframe based on a unique group id. the problem is that this code takes 3 days to run so I am trying to figure how to do this is in parallel using multiprocessing. Please advise

```
for group in dfA['GROUP_ID']:
    dftest = dfA.loc[dfA['GROUP_ID'] == group]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Dask](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) has direct support for pandas and allows for parallel computing on one machine or distributed.

> Dask is composed of two components:
>
> 1. Dynamic task scheduling optimized for computation. This is similar to Airflow, Luigi, Celery, or Make, but optimized for interactive computational workloads.
> 2. “Big Data” collections like parallel arrays, dataframes, and lists that extend common interfaces like NumPy, Pandas, or Python iterators to larger-than-memory or distributed environments. These parallel collections run on top of the dynamic task schedulers.

From the docs a simple pandas example:

```
import pandas as pd                     
df = pd.read_csv('2015-01-01.csv')      
df.groupby(df.user_id).value.mean()
```

and the same in dask:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('2015-*-*.csv')
df.groupby(df.user_id).value.mean().compute()
```

Comment: I am actually creating this dataframe from a SQL query to a snowflake database. Do you have an example of this using a query to a database.

Comment: Essentially I want to process on "GROUP_ID" at a time. There are 1.7 million group_id ' s and a group_id may contain up to 7 thousand customer records (if that makes sense). There can be up to 7 thousand customers with the same group id.

Comment: Dask can [read SQL tables](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_sql_table).

Comment: so how do I establish a connection to SnowFlake database. Can you show me an example of that? Please